# Assign pass to a function in Python

Tags: python, function, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I have a piece of code that defines a function that takes a function as an argument, like so:

```
def stuff(n, f):
  f(n)
```

Now, I want to provide some default value of f that does nothing. So I figured I'd use pass, like so:

```
def stuff(n, f = None):
  if(f is None):
    f = pass
  f(n)
```

But this does not compile. How should I be doing this?

Comment: About the formatting: do not leave spaces around the `=` in the signature of a function.

Comment: While we're nitting the formatting, don't use less than 4 spaces for indentation--2 spaces is essentially unreadable--and don't put parentheses around conditionals as if you're writing C.

Comment: What everybody is saying is that you should read the [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Ah, my C++/Java/Perl background is showing =P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `pass` is a keyword for the interpreter, a place holder for otherwise nothing. It's not an object that you can assign. You can use a no-op lambda.

```
f = lambda x: None
```

Comment: OT, but why would the designers need to create a new keyword just for a noop? bizarre

Comment: @jberryman because Python doesn't have block delimiters. In languages that do you would typically write `{}`. But in Python it would be... nothing. So `pass` is there to make it syntactically complete.

Comment: @jberryman Where? `pass` is just a keyword to act as a placeholder for otherwise empty block. It probably makes parsing easier. It's not an object. None is an object that means no other value. They have different semantics.

Answer (score 9):

Why not simply this ?

```
def stuff(n, f=None):
    if f is None:
        return
    return f(n)
```

Comment: Minor improvement: [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) advises to use `is None` instead of `== None` ([rationale](http://jaredgrubb.blogspot.com/2009/04/python-is-none-vs-none.html)).

Comment: Thanks, I'd wondered which was best but never thought to check ! Answer fixed accordingly.

Comment: +1 Much better than the other solutions since it clearly states the intent.

Comment: As far as this question has a "correct" answer, this is it.  The other answers all needlessly obfuscate such a trivial function.

Comment: If the OP wants to pass the function object on to another function, this approach does not work.

Comment: Man, I'd love to give you the answer...while this does answer exactly how I described the issue, my description was oversimplified...in my program, stuff does more than call f(n) and f(n) is called multiple times. If I could pick two answers, though,I'd pick this.

Comment: No problem ! I as Space_C0wb0y pointed out, the correct answer depended on your exact scenario so I figured you'd pick whichever suited best :)

Answer (score 5):

A little shorter:

```
def stuff(n, f=None):
  f = f or (lambda x: None)
  f(n)
```

Or even better:

```
def stuff(n, f=None):
    f(n) if f is not None else None
```

Comment: Is your first version Python3K ? That syntax does not appear to be valid for python 2.7.

Comment: @Bethor: Thanks, fixed. Tested on 2.6.

Comment: or even simpler: `def stuff(n, f = None): f and f(n)`

Comment: @codecraft: Indeed. But I would argue that in this case clarity suffers needlessly.

Comment: agreed. Using logical operators for control flow makes things really perl-like and is probably not very pythonic

Comment: Ick: don't use the ternary operator as flow control!  This answer is encouraging optimizing for line count instead of, and at the expense of, clarity.

Comment: @Glenn: I agree that my answer is not good for the case where the function has not return value, and only the side effect counts. But, would you agree that this would be fine if the focus was on the return value?

Comment: I don't see any advantage to this over Bethor's answer.

Comment: @Glenn: I have been thinking, and I agree that Bethor's answer is better, except for the case when the function object itself will be passed as argument to other functions.

Answer (score 4):

You can't assing empty. But you can creaty internal function, that you will assign to `f`.

```
def stuff(n, f=None):
  def empty(n):
    pass
  if f is None:
    f = empty
  f(n)
```

Answer (score 3):

The generic noop function :

```
f = lambda *x,**y:None
```

You can call

```
f()
f(0,foo=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a

```
def nop(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def algo(func=nop):
    do_something()
    func()
    do_something_else()

algo() # nop is called
algo(some_callback) # some_callback is called
```

IMHO looks cleaner than

```
if foo:
    foo()
```